# android app future.usb.usbmanager

Tags: android

I'm having some problems running my app on a new android tablet I bought. It was working on my previous android cell phone. Here's my logcat output --

```
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.future.usb.UsbManager
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at edu.uidaho.pong.PongActivity.setupAccessory(PongActivity.java:111)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at edu.uidaho.pong.PongActivity.onCreate(PongActivity.java:44)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-23 16:13:12.250: E/AndroidRuntime(12284):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html

The solution is using android.hardware.usb instead of com.android.future.usb

Some lines of code had to be changed as well to match the android.hardware.usb version. Everything you need is in the included link.