# Can't import com.android.future.usb.*

Tags: android, adk, mbed

I'm following the steps to use ADK to control mbed via the Android Studio

however their mbed [adkport code](http://mbed.org/cookbook/mbed-with-Android-ADK) (Scroll down to adkport hyperlink) requires these imports

```
import com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory;
import com.android.future.usb.UsbManager;
```

I've noticed another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9842697/android-app-future-usb-usbmanager/9878148#9878148) that suggested the developer's solution was to switch it to android.hardware.usb, but when I do that, 3 different lines won't work because the hardware based package doesn't support  **getAccessory** and **getInstance** symbols

Any solutions to this problem? Can't get my head around it

I tried following the steps for replacing the code to use android.hardware.usb instead but I still get an issue with their own [android developer routine](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html)

```
     //mManager = UsbManager.getInstance(context);
    UsbManager mManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

however now it doesn't recognize getSystemService

Here's where it fails.

```
public void setup(Context context)
{

    //mManager = UsbManager.getInstance(context);
    UsbManager mManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);  //<-----
    UsbAccessory[] accessoryList = mManager.getAccessoryList();
    PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
            new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    context.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
    mManager.requestPermission(accessoryList[0], mPermissionIntent);


    if (accessoryList[0] != null) {

        mAccessory = accessoryList[0];
        if(mManager.hasPermission(mAccessory))
        {
        openAccessory(mAccessory);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Search http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html for the add-on symbols and you will find their replacements.

Comment: Thank, seems to be helping make progress, question edited for further difficulty encountered with this approach.

Comment: "getSystemService" is quite generic beyond just the USB apis.  But it is a method of Context, and perhaps you are trying to call it within a class that does not extend Context?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm using context easily in other parts of the same code. I'll update the question with that section that doesn't work well

Comment: If you are passing in the valid Context as an argument because the class in which this occurs is not a subclass of Context, then you should call the method of the context passed as an argument, ie in your case, `context.getSystemService()` rather than trying to call this (non-existent?) method of your current class, which is what happens when you just type the method without specifying a Context.

Answer (score 1):

> `getSystemService()` is a method that can be called from inside an `activity` or from inside a non-activity class using `context` of an activity.

Since your function `setup()` should be called by passing a `Context`,
`usbManager = (UsbManager) context.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments (from Morrison Chang) should actually be copied as an answer (worked for me in similar situation).

His suggestion to read [USB Accessory](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#usage) is spot on. Distilled instructions:

1. Make sure your manifested minSdkVersion is high enough (For me it was 19).
2. Replace `UsbManager.getInstance(this)` with `(UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE)`.
3. Replace `UsbManager.getAccessory(intent)` with `intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY)`.